# No se ve texto de Cardview en un recyclerview en un fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, recyclerview, cardview

Tengo un problema que ya no se que hacer para solucionarlo... He creado un CardView con el siguiente código

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:backgroundTint="#00BCD4"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cardImgAula"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/birrete"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/linearCardAulas"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearCardAulas"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/cardImgAula"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardAsig26"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:fontFamily="@font/fredoka"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="PROGRAMACIÓN DE SERVICIOS Y PROCESOS"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_weight="3"

                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/cardAula26"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="L15"
                android:fontFamily="@font/fredoka"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Que debería verse así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He creado las siguientes clases para hacer el RecyclerView

```
public class ElementosCardView {

    public String asignatura;
    public String aula;

    public ElementosCardView(String asignatura, String aula) {
        asignatura = asignatura;
        aula = aula;
    }

    public String getAsignatura() {
        return asignatura;
    }

    public void setAsignatura(String asignatura) {
        this.asignatura = asignatura;
    }

    public String getAula() {
        return aula;
    }

    public void setAula(String aula) {
        this.aula = aula;
    }
}
```

El adaptador

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AdaptadorAulas extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorAulas.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ElementosCardView> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;


    public AdaptadorAulas(ArrayList<ElementosCardView> itemlist, Context context){

        this.mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData= itemlist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){

        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptadorAulas.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_estructura, parent, false);
        return new AdaptadorAulas.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AdaptadorAulas.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        /*String asignatura = mData.get(position).getAsignatura();
        String aula = mData.get(position).getAula();
        holder.asignatura.setText(asignatura);
        holder.aula.setText(aula);*/
        holder.bindData(mData.get(position));

    }


    public void setItems ( ArrayList<ElementosCardView> items){

        mData=items;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView asignatura, aula;

        ViewHolder (View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            asignatura = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardAsig26);
            aula =itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardAula26);
        }
        void bindData (final ElementosCardView item){

            asignatura.setText(item.getAsignatura());
            aula.setText(item.getAula());
            //asignatura.setText(asignatura.getText());
            //aula.setText(aula.getText());

        }
    }

}
```

Y el fragmento en el que se aplica todo

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Aulas extends Fragment {


    View vista;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList <ElementosCardView> elementos;
    public Aulas() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aulas, container, false);

        init();

        return vista;
    }


    public void init(){

        elementos = new ArrayList<>();
        elementos.add(new ElementosCardView("ACCESO A DATOS", "L16"));
        elementos.add(new ElementosCardView("INGLÉS", "L14"));
        elementos.add(new ElementosCardView("DESARROLLO DE INTERFACES", "L17"));
        elementos.add(new ElementosCardView("EIE", "L15"));
        elementos.add(new ElementosCardView("PROGRAMACIÓN DE SERVICIOS", "L15"));


        AdaptadorAulas adaptadorAulas = new AdaptadorAulas(elementos,getContext() );
        recyclerView = vista.findViewById(R.id.reciclerAulas);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptadorAulas);
        
    }
}
```

Y se me ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya no se que más probar para que se vea el texto que meto en el arraylist.

Algunas partes que se ven comentadas en el adaptador me han dado la opción de ver el texto que viene en el cardview, pero no se pone el texto que incluyo en el arraylist.
Esta claro que algo del add del arraylist lo reconoce porque me saca 5 elementos, pero el texto no lo saca en los cardview

Muchas gracias por si me podéis ayudar!!

El logcat no me da ningún error por cierto

Saludos!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para asegurar asignar los valores: `asignatura`, `aula`, se guarden correctamente, en el constructor del objeto `ElementosCardView` usa `this`:

```
public class ElementosCardView {

    ...
    ...

    public ElementosCardView(String asignatura, String aula) {
        //asignatura = asignatura;
        this.asignatura = asignatura;
        //aula = aula;
        this.aula = aula;
    }

  ...
  ...

}
```

Me parece que esto es el problema que no permite actualizar estos valores y se puedan desplegar en tu CardView.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Jorgesys! Era exactamente eso, lo solucioné. Mil gracias!

Comment: Excelente noticia! , saludos @VictordeMendozaEsteban